# Tensorflow Lite and edgetpu_compiler: Compiling for version 10 gives "Internal compiler error. Aborting!"

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-lite, google-coral

I am attempting to compile the code at [this Coral example on Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google-coral/tutorials/blob/master/retrain_classification_ptq_tf1.ipynb#scrollTo=ZmiHICezwXZq) to run on runtime version 10, since I have a Coral USB Accelerator connected to a [customized build for Raspberry Pi Zero W](https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu-platforms).

The command I'd like to get working is

```sh
edgetpu_compiler --min_runtime_version 10 [.TFLITE file]
```

It always ends with an internal error; unknown to me why that would be...? The error is:

```
Edge TPU Compiler version 2.1.302470888

Internal compiler error. Aborting!
```

To reproduce this, you should do the import, preparation, build, and first training steps. No need to fine-tune: results are the same.

I understand that certain operations are not available for lower runtimes, but I am at a loss at what exactly would need to change in the demo so as to compile it successfully.

Does anyone know what might be missing, or otherwise provide guidance?

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: Edited above to clarify error message and steps necessary to reproduce it.

Comment: Hi, I can look into this, but any reason for not using a newer runtime version? Also, I don't have the model in hand could you kindly upload it?

Answer (score 0):

just got a chance to check this out, looks like there is actually a bug preventing compilation at older runtime version...
This is fixed as I'm able to compile this model with `-m 10` form the code base, it'll be fixed for you by next release. For now here is a work around (essentially checking out an older compiler version to compile the model):

```
$ git clone https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu.git && cd edgetpu
$ git checkout 657d2b6
$ ./compiler/x86_64/edgetpu_compiler -s -m 10 /path/to/model
```

This should works, although with an older runtime, many ops weren't supported then so you may not see the performance increase that you would with the current runtime version!

Comment: Hey @Nam Vu! Was caught in something else and was unable to respond to your last question. Will try this out soon. The reason for the old runtime is that I'm using a Raspberry Pi Zero W which AFAIK is not compatible with the newer runtimes (ref: https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu-platforms)

Comment: Hi I see, sorry for the confusion, but we just stopped creating new images for newer runtime version because it's became infeasible to maintain and support. We still release libedgetpu for different platform (I believe the pi zero is armv6) [here](https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu/tree/master/libedgetpu/throttled). If it doesn't, we do plan on open sourcing libedgetpu if you want to take a stab at compiling it :) (I don't have a timeframe on when it'll be opensourced, unfortunately).

Anyhow, for now I suggest using my above solution to compile the model, works for me.

Comment: Thanks again. Verified that it builds just fine, though I get an error while running a run-of-the-mill Python classification script: "RuntimeError: Error in interpreter initialization.".

Honestly, I'll just get myself a regular Pi and use the Zero W for other stuff, since that's the main culprit here. Thanks again!